# Permutations of 4 people in a line

Tags: permutations, gre-exam

This question is from the GRE math:

`A group of 4 people are standing in a straight line. In how many different ways can these people be standing on the line?`

The answer is $24$. If the permutations formula is this, how did they derive this answer? Thanks.

$$\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$$

Comment: The number of permutations on $n$ objects is $n!$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the $4$ people can be the first person. Then, there are $3$ remaining choices for the second person, then $2$ remaining choices for the third, and then the fourth has been decided.

Hence, there are $n!$ possible ways.